# How can I pass the data to the callKit in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, pushkit

I am trying to pass the data received from `VoIP` push notification to `CallKit` so when I click on answer button I can send this data to the `deep link` and open app with this data/deep link.

Main question it to access data from callKit while clicking on answer button.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult.  You have the call data from the push notification. You need to store that somewhere that you can get it later. You report a new incoming call.  When you get a callback to your `CXProvider` delegate telling you that the call was answered you can use the information that you have already received in the push notification.